# What should a computer science student do if there is no passion to work?

Tags: software-industry, internship, work-experience, technology

I am interning at a company right now. I believe I have been given an awful project that I cannot cope with which has lead me to believe that I am not cut out be software engineer. I like technology and would like to able to use the knowledge I have. What can I do about it?

Comment: Step 1) find out what you don't like Step 2) find out what you do like Step 3) combine 1) and 2)

Comment: Also, this question is currently too broad. There are too many valid answers, and "what can I do" is not something we can answer. If you can narrow it down to something more specific (like what you don't like, what you would like to do, and what knowledge you have that you want to use) we might be able to assist.

Comment: To give up on a career because of one bad experience may be too rash.

Comment: Like any scientist will tell you: a trial with one participant is basically invalid. You need multiple and more varied experiences to reach the conclusion of "I am not cut out to be a software engineer".

Answer (score 4):

## Ask for help

Work isn't always fun and most of the time you just have to buckle down and get things done.  Getting the uninteresting things out the way means that you move onto something else that might be more interesting.  The better you do, the more things open up.

For now, get some help to get over this immediate hurdle.  If you can't cope, raise this as a problem and discuss ways in which you can get things sorted with your mentor/supervisor.

It's important that you identify what you're having problems with - you won't get marked down for knowing where your current limits are if you're willing to learn.

Or you can quit.